# Some intuition for $\sin\left(x+\frac\pi5\right)+\sin\left(x+\frac{3\pi}5\right)+\sin\left(x+\frac{7\pi}5\right)+\sin\left(x+\frac{9\pi}5\right)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone give me some intuition how to start solving this equation please? Or maybe fastway to understand that this whole thing is equal to $\sin(x) = 1$.

> $$\sin\left(x+\frac\pi5\right)+\sin\left(x+\frac{3\pi}5\right)+\sin\left(x+\frac{7\pi}5\right)+\sin\left(x+\frac{9\pi}5\right)=1$$

Thank you!

Comment: Have you at least looked at using the compound angle identity?  $$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$

Comment: Using complex variable $z=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
& \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{5}) + \sin(x + \frac{3\pi}{5})  + \sin(x + \frac{7\pi}{5})  + \sin(x + \frac{9\pi}{5}) \\
=& \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{5})+ \sin(x - \frac{\pi}{5})
 + \sin(x + \frac{3\pi}{5})  + \sin(x -\frac{3\pi}{5})  \\
=& 2\sin x \cos\frac\pi5 + 2\sin x \cos\frac{3\pi}5\\
= & 2\sin x (\cos\frac\pi5 + \cos\frac{3\pi}5)= \sin x
\end{align}

Thus, $\sin x =1$, or $x= \frac\pi2+n\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi:=e^{2\pi i/5}$ so this is equivalent to$$1=\Im[e^{i(x+\pi/5)}(1+\xi+\xi^3+\xi^4)]=-\Im[e^{i(x+\pi/5)}\xi^2].$$Since $-i$ is the only unit complex number of imaginary part $-1$,$$e^{i(x+\pi/5)}=-i\xi^{-2}=e^{-\pi i/2-4\pi i/5}=e^{7\pi i/10+2n\pi},\,n\in\Bbb Z,$$with solution $x=\pi/2+2n\pi,\,n\in\Bbb Z$, i.e. $\sin x=1$.

Note: an older version of the question use $5\pi/5$ instead of $7\pi/5$, so we'd have$$1=\Im[e^{i(x+\pi/5)}(1+\xi+\xi^2+\xi^4)]=-\Im[e^{i(x+\pi/5)}\xi^3].$$The same logic as before would obtain $x=\pi/10+2n\pi$, i.e. $\cos(x-\pi/10)=1$, in agreement with @MichaelRozenberg's treatment.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to $\cos(x-18^{\circ})=1.$

Use $\sin18^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}$ and $\cos36^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4}$

Because
$$\sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{5}\right) + \sin\left(x + \frac{3\pi}{5}\right)  + \sin\left(x + \frac{5\pi}{5}\right)  + \sin\left(x + \frac{9\pi}{5}\right)=\cos(x-18^{\circ}).$$
The problem was changed.

Comment: @J.G The problem was changed.

Comment: Now it's much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

As $\sin5x=2^{5-1}\sin^5x-5\cdot2^{5-3}\sin^{5-2}x+5\sin x$

If $\sin5y=-\sin5x=\sin(\pi+5x)$

$y=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}5+x$  where $n=0,1,2,3,4$

So, the roots of $$2^{5-1}\sin^5x-5\cdot2^{5-3}\sin^{5-2}x+5\sin x=-\sin5x$$ are  $\sin\left(\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}5+x\right)$  where $n=0,1,2,3,4$

Using Vieta's formula $$\sum_{n=0}^4\sin\left(\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}5+x\right)=\dfrac0{2^4}$$

But what if $n=2?$